# CSS Sprite Navigation Issue

Tags: css, html-lists, sprite

I have built a CSS Sprite Navigation.  The Navigation functions fine unless you have the UL list in a differnt order than the style sheet, or don't use all of the li elements.
You can see the examples here:
http://www.reneebuller.com/_temp/navigation.html (works)
http://www.reneebuller.com/_temp/navigation1.html (nav2 and nav3 are switched)
(Then go to nagvigation2.html  nav 2 is deleted... sory I can't post another link because I'm a newbie and limited to two)

You will see in the later two examples that something happened with text.  I can't figure out what is goin on.

Comment: example 2 isnt working I think. The menu is not rendering at all

Comment: you can post other link on coments

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the name of the IDs as well. This is bugged:

```
<li id="navThree"><a class="" href="#">Two</a></li>
```

This will work just fine even if inverted:

```
<li id="navThree"><a class="" href="#">Three</a></li>
<li id="navTwo"><a class="" href="#">Two</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any of the CSS in the second example that was used in the first.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have seen you have made totally image based navigation i think you can easily make this navigation through pure css and than you can make changes easily in css navigation.

please check i have made pure css based navigation similar like your navigation i hope this will help you:- http://jsfiddle.net/YRjE8/10/